# Autocomplete works in Chrome not IE

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer, autocomplete, fill

OK, so here is my situation. I recently rewrote an ancient .asp website running ProvideX into a new VB.Net platform. I am receiving complaints from my users (which are running older versions of IE) that their auto fill stopped working on the new system. For example if I type "Apple" in a field over and over again eventually the browser should start recommending "Apple" in a list so I don't have to type it again when I click in that box. This works perfectly in Chrome on the new website. For whatever reason IE is not making any suggestions. I am able to replicate these results on my IE browser as well and I am also able to confirm that my browser is auto filling on some of our other websites. Does anybody have any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: I would, but honestly I am not even sure what part of it I would show. I think I have narrowed down the issue, but I am still not sure how to solve it. The new website is being seen by the browser as a "form" and the old one is not. I was able to get IE 11 to Auto Fill by checking Forms under the Auto Fill settings. IE 10 on the other hand already has it checked and it is still not working. 

Keep in mind I am just referring to the default auto fill behavior and not a custom javascript auto fill. The users are just wanting it to suggest things that they have typed previously.

Comment: ah ok - i personally am not too familiar with programming web stuff - are you using asp.net? you might want to edit your post to add that tag or whichever one is relevant. I just spotted your post because of the vb tag. Hope you get some helpful answers though.

Comment: Yes, I am using asp.net. Thanks for the tip. I have updated my tags to include asp.net.